# Migrate data from one openldap to another one

Tags: openldap

I try to do a migration from one ldap (Ubuntu) to another one (CentOS)

From actual server I do an export of database and values:

```
slapcat -n 0 -l slapd.conf
slapcat -n 1 -l slapd.ldif
```

At the other one I try to load data but I get this error:

```
[root@oldap01 tmp]# slapadd -f slapd.ldif
5e442f2b slapd.ldif: line 1: unknown directive <dn:> outside backend info and database definitions.
slapadd: bad configuration file!
```

slapd.ldif start by:

```
dn:
objectClass: top
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
o: no-domain
dc: no-domain
structuralObjectClass: organization
```

There's any way to create manually the OU,CN,... and then import the values?
Thanks in advance